# Apple Watch - Get Width of Elements Programmatically - WKInterfaceTable, WKInterfaceGroup

Tags: ios, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacegroup

How can I get the width of apple watch elements programmatically?

WKInterfaceTable, WKInterfaceGroup, etc

Comment: I don't think this is possible - "WatchKit provides one-way communication between the interface objects in your extension and the corresponding interface elements in your watchOS app. You can set the values of an interface object, but you cannot get the current values. If you want to know the current value of an attribute, you must save the value yourself." (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceobject)

Comment: Moreover, even if you'll get to know about the values, there's no way you can set the values. Curious, why you want to get that?